Langchain: LCEL-Chain with history returns "AI: AI: AI: Assistant:" in answer
I have built a RAG app with Langchain which uses chat history. Generally everything works, however when calling the chain I often see (not always) "AI: AI: AI: Assistant:" before the actual response starts (see example in the screenshot). What could be reasons for this?

Here is my code:
import box
import yaml
from langchain_community.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
import torch
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from .prompts import mistral_prompt, no_rag_prompt, chat_history_prompt
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from operator import itemgetter
from typing import List
from langchain_core.chat_history import BaseChatMessageHistory
from langchain_core.messages import BaseMessage
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field
from langchain_core.runnables import (
    RunnableLambda,
    ConfigurableFieldSpec,
    RunnablePassthrough,
)
from langchain_core.runnables.history import RunnableWithMessageHistory

from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
chat_history_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        (
        "system",
        "Du bist RagBot, ein hilfsbereiter Assistent. Antworte nur auf Deutsch. Nutze für deine Antwort ausschließlich folgenden Kontext:\n\n### Kontext zur Frage. Falls dieser eine leere Liste ist, antworte, dass du nicht genügend Kontextinformationen finden konntest ###:\n\n{context}",
        ),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
        ("human", 
         "{question}"),
    ]
)

# From here all belongs to the chain with Chat History
class InMemoryHistory(BaseChatMessageHistory, BaseModel):
    """In memory implementation of chat message history."""

    messages: List[BaseMessage] = Field(default_factory=list)

    def add_message(self, message: BaseMessage) -> None:
        """Add a self-created message to the store and keep only the last 2 entries."""
        if len(self.messages) >= 4:  # If there are already 2 messages,
            self.messages.pop(0)  # remove the oldest one
        self.messages.append(message)  # Then append the new message

    def clear(self) -> None:
        self.messages = []
        
store = {}

def get_session_history(user_id: str, conversation_id: str) -> BaseChatMessageHistory:
    if (user_id, conversation_id) not in store:
        store[(user_id, conversation_id)] = InMemoryHistory()
    return store[(user_id, conversation_id)]

def chain_with_chat_history(retriever, llm):
    context = itemgetter("question") | retriever
    first_step = RunnablePassthrough.assign(context=context)
    chain = (
        first_step
        | chat_history_prompt
        | llm
        | StrOutputParser()
    )
    
    with_message_history = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
        chain,
        get_session_history=get_session_history,
        input_messages_key="question",
        history_messages_key="history",
        history_factory_config=[
            ConfigurableFieldSpec(
                id="user_id",
                annotation=str,
                name="User ID",
                description="Unique identifier for the user.",
                default="",
                is_shared=True,
            ),
            ConfigurableFieldSpec(
                id="conversation_id",
                annotation=str,
                name="Conversation ID",
                description="Unique identifier for the conversation.",
                default="",
                is_shared=True,
            ),
        ],
    )
    print(f"CHAT HISTORY STORE: {store}")
    return with_message_history

I am using a ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages to set up the MessagePlaceHolder to store the last 2 question-answer pairs in the memory. Afterwards I am creating the chain and the history chain which I am calling in a streaming response like this:
def chain_with_history_generator(question, db_path):
    retriever = load_retriever(db_path=db_path, embeddings=embeddings)
    chain = chain_with_chat_history(retriever=retriever, llm=llm)
    for response in chain.stream({"question": question},config={"configurable": {"user_id": "user_id", "conversation_id": "conversation_id"}},): #UserID and Conversation ID has to be adjusted, depending on authentication
        yield response

